# Jenkins default rule for project-based security

Tags: jenkins

I have set up Jenkins for project-based security to allow certain users access to particular projects.  However, the default rule seems in the matrix refers to anonymous users and it seems like all authenticated users can still view the project.

Is there a catch-all user for authenticated users in Jenkins?

Regards,

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-13029), starting with version 1.480.1+ you can use the `authenticated` group

Project-based security is a "2 phase config" scenario, involving global and project configuration. To achieve what you want, you should grant:

1. only `OVERALL - READ` to **anonymous** and **authenticated** in jenkins global security, so they can access jenkins
2. desired users with appropriate permissions in project configuration